# Linear Combination of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, variance, moment-generating-functions, expected-value

I am working on a problem and am a bit stuck

**The problem:** For independent random variables

X ~ N(-1,3)

Y ~ N(0,2)

Z ~ N(4,1)

Consider U:= 2X - 4Y - Z + 5

Find the Expectation, variance, and MGF for U.

**What I have done so far:**

Fx(t) = **E**e$^{tX}$ = exp(-t + $3t^2\over2$)

Fy(t) = **E**e$^{tY}$ = exp(0t + t$^2$)

Fz(t) = **E**e$^{tZ}$ = exp(4t + $t^2\over2$)

Then MGF of U:

Fu(t) = **E**e$^{t(2X-4Y-Z+5)}$ = **E**[e$^{(2t)X}$e$^{(-4t)Y}$e$^{(-t)Z}$e$^{(5t)}$] =

e$^{(5t)}$**E**e$^{(2t)X}$**E**e$^{(-4t)Y}$**E**e$^{(-t)Z}$ = e$^{(5t)}$Fx(2t)Fy(-4t)Fz(-1t) =

exp(5t) exp(-(2t) + $3(2t)^2\over2$) exp(0(-4t) + (-4t)$^2$) exp(4(-1t) + $(-1t)^2\over2$) =

exp(5t -2t +0t -4t + 6t$^2$ +16t$^2$ + $1\over2$$t^2$) = exp(-1t + 22.5t$^2$) =

U ~ N(-1, 22.5)

Then for Expectation:

F'u(t) =

But here is where I am stuck. How do we find the Expectation of U (how do we take this derivative) and how do we find the Variance of U? Also, does the first part look correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecation is linear.

$$E[U]= 2E[X] - 4E[Y] - E[Z] + 5$$

Also, since they are independent.

$$Var[U]= 2^2Var[X] + 4^2Var[Y] + Var[Z] $$

Remark:

- Usually we use $F$ for CDF and $M$ for mgf.
- $U$ is again a normal distribution and after you find out the mean and variance, figuring out the mgf should be easy.

Comment: To clarify though, to find these expectations we need to take the derivative of the MFGs correct? ie. M'x(t) = M'x(0) = EX and M''x(t) = M''x(0) = E(X$^2$)

Comment: that's just one of the way. but here we are given that $X \sim N(-1,3)$, clearly we know $E[X]=-1$ and $Var(X)=3$ and we can compute the second moment from there.

Comment: Ok, that clears things up. Thank you.